# How does GDB know optimized out local variable values?

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, x86-64

When I compile the following code with `gcc -g -O1 t.c`

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    int d = 4;

    return 0;
}
```

GCC optimize out all unused local variables. This can be seen by GDB `disassemble` command, only instructions for `return 0` were left:

```
(gdb) disassemble main 
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000401106 <+0>: mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040110b <+5>: ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

However, GDB somehow knows the values of variables from C code

```
(gdb) info locals 
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
```

How does GDB know about these values if they are absent in generated assembly code?

Comment: Debug symbols are included in the executable unless they are removed as part of the build process. Thats how GDB knows about any symbols. When you compile C, all symbols (function names, vars, etc.) go away as they are just there to help you program. The only way any debugger knows is that they are included in debug info in the executable.

Comment: @siride You could post that as an answer to the question.

Comment: Then what is the point of storing them in debug symbols if the variables were optimized out in resulting binary?

Comment: If you look at generated assembly code either via `gcc -S` or equivalently on godbolt.org, you will see stuff like `.section .debug_info,"",@progbits` and in that section, although not generally human readable, you can spot the information.

Comment: @ks1322: What's the point?  If your program wasn't so trivial, but instead included an expression like `arr[ i + a ]`. you could copy-paste that expression into GDB and have it evaluate correctly if it has a value for `a` from debug symbols, and actual info on where `i` and `arr` live in the program's memory at run-time.

Comment: @ikegami thats what Peter was saying, though. Those optimized variables could be part of an expression and it's useful to know what they would be if they hadn't been optimized out.

Comment: @PeterCordes I see, that makes sense, but the fact that debug info and generated assembly can diverge confused me a bit.

Comment: I assume it makes sense to you now.  Remember that debug info is for debugging *C* programs.  You don't need debug info for asm-level debugging, the machine code and architectural state are all there is.  (Although I guess maybe backtraces and changing stack frames could be useful.)

Comment: @Jester, I see the values in `.Ldebug_info0` section, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted in comments, GCC stores variable values in debug info. It is possible to see them in GDB because GCC generates [extra debug info](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Var_Tracking_Assignments) when doing optimized build. Extra GCC options `-fvar-tracking` and `-fvar-tracking-assignments` are implicitly enabled in this case. If disable this extra debug info, GDB outputs `<optimized out>` as usual.

If to build with `gcc -fno-var-tracking -g -O1 t.c`, GDB output is:

```
(gdb) i locals 
a = <optimized out>
b = <optimized out>
c = <optimized out>
d = <optimized out>
```

However if to build without optimization and without var-tracking with `gcc -fno-var-tracking -g -O0 t.c`, GDB can get values from unoptimized code:

```
(gdb) i locals 
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
```

Answer (score 4):

The message that a value was optimized out doesn't mean that a variable got optimized away. It means that the information needed to determine the variable's value is no longer available, possibly because it was overwritten or reused to hold a different variable. Here's an example of that happening:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int x = argc + 42;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile that with `gcc -g -O3`. If you do `start` and then `step`, you'll be able to do `print x` and see its value, even though it's never actually calculated by the program, because the debugging information says how the value would have been calculated. But if you then do `next` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> an extra time to let `getchar` return, now `print x` will tell you that the value was optimized out. That's because the only copy of `argc` the program had access to was in `rdi`, which got clobbered by `getchar`, and the compiler didn't bother to save its old value first since the program doesn't need it afterwards.